# Magento 2.3.4 ImageMagick 7.0.9-20 Q16 issue

Tags: magento2, php-7.2, magento2.3.4

Just testing upgrade form `2.3.3 to 2.3.4` and noticed there is an issue with **ImageMagick** display of product images. On category pages, some images are missing and on product view page no images are appearing at all. Reverting to the PHP gd image processor in backend resolves issue and all images appear correctly (apart from png image with transparent backgrounds which appear black - reason for using ImageMagick).
ImageMagick is correctly shown in phpinfo and seems to be working fine for 2.3.3 which installed on the same server.. any ideas? running PHP 7.2 on centos 6.

Comment: Flush Catalog Images Cache and then check.

Comment: Thanks already, flushed, rebuilt static & reindexed.. interestingly if you click the image it appears in the popup.

Comment: also some images give this on product page Exception #0 (Exception): Unsupported image format. File: magento path//////image.png

Answer (score 0):

Mnaged to resolve. I compile from source and was missing delegate libraries for png files this was taking preference over yum installation.. png  I managed to remove with make uninstall then after some trouble finally managed to install with yum using ImageMagick 6.7.2-7 2017.